# Setting up a bootable usb iso

Tags: boot, grub2

So, I've got an `ext3` partition on a removable USB device. Its `/dev/sdb1` on my system.

After mounting this partition:

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/USB
```

I install grub on it:

```
 sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/USB /dev/sdb1
```

Grub installs without any errors. Next, I copy the `iso` image to this partition's root:

```
 /mnt/USB/ubuntu.iso
```

Now I add a grub conf file at `/mnt/USB/boot/grub/grub.cfg` :

```
menuentry "Run Ubuntu Live ISO" {
 loopback loop /ubuntu.iso
 linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso splash --
 initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

All good, Reboot . . .

But **grub never loads the menu entry** !! , it just starts into grub prompt.

Can anyone explain what goes wrong ?